# Newton-Raphson in Extereme Optimization library

Tags: c#

I am working on a project that needs Newton-Raphson method. For solving the equation i am using Extreme Optimization Library. The answer it returns is a object and i cant use it in calculation. How can i change it to vector!?

we can see example in https://www.extremeoptimization.com/QuickStart/CSharp/NonlinearSystems.aspx

in that exmple we see "Result" as a property of  NewtonRaphsonSystemSolver and the type is a object but i want it as a vector

Comment: Is the Extreme Optimization Library an external library that you have referenced? Can you provide the link to this library? Posting some code snippets would also help to allow for people to analyze what could be the issue you are having.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. In order to help you with a question, you must provide us with sufficient details to reproduce the problem. In it's current state your question is very unclear. Please expand it.